# Save Excel file from API request using FileSaver in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, filesaver.js

Im my React app, I'm querying an API to retrieve an export of the database under excel format. The call is performed inside my sagas. I then try to save the response of the API with FileSaver

```
const {headers, data} = response;
FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([data], {type: headers['content-type']}), filename);
```

The headers of the response are as follow

```
{
    content-disposition: "attachment; filename="export.xlsx"; filename*=utf-8''export.xlsx;",
    content-type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
}
```

When I call the API with Postman and save the file, I can then open it like any standard excel file. But when I save it with FileSaver I cannot open it. It's just hexadecimal encoding. What am I missing to save the file the right way ?

Comment: Did you get a solution? I am facing a similar issue here

Answer (score 0):

If the data is a dataframe, you could use Danfo.js:

https://danfo.jsdata.org/api-reference/input-output/danfo.to_excel

```
const dfd = require("danfojs-node")

let data = {
    Abs: [20.2, 30, 47.3],
    Count: [34, 4, 5],
    "country code": ["NG", "FR", "GH"],
};

let df = new dfd.DataFrame(data);

dfd.toExcel(df, { filePath: "testOut.xlsx"});
```